# How do I click on a specific position of an element using playwright?

Tags: typescript, web-scraping, playwright

I am scraping data from a dynamic website, so some actions need to occur for the data to be loaded into the DOM. There is a horizontal scroll bar that I need to click, and so far, I can perform this action. However, it would be more interesting if I could simulate the action of clicking at a specific position, such as to the right of this element. Is there a way to do this?

```
    const iframe = page.frameLocator('iframe[allowfullscreen]');
    await iframe.locator('div.tableEx > div:nth-child(7)').click();
```

What I tried worked as expected, now I want to direct this click to a specific position in the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `boundingBox` of the element and then use the `mouse` property to click on any coordinate based on the element's bounding box.

```
test('Click at position', async ({ context, page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.mabl.com");
  var element = page.locator('"Login"');
  var box = (await element.boundingBox())!;
  await page.mouse.click(box.x + box.width / 2, box.y + box.height - 5);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to check the docs because the thing you want to do is often an option on the action.

In this case, [`locator.click()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-click) accepts a `position` option:

```js
await iframe
  .locator('div.tableEx > div:nth-child(7)')
  .click({position: {x: 23, y: 32}});
```

The docs describe `position` as

> A point to use relative to the top-left corner of element padding box. If not specified, uses some visible point of the element.

That said, this isn't usually necessary, so I question whether you're not falling into an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Furthermore, CSS selectors in general, and hyper-specific indexing like `nth-child(7)` are discouraged since they tend to break as soon as the page structure changes.

Sharing full context would help avoid these issues, since there might be a much better way to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do. For example, scrolling can be done with [`scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-scroll-into-view-if-needed), [`keyboard.press({key: "PageDown"})`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-press), or a [`mouse.wheel(0, 500)`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-mouse#mouse-wheel) action. If you're scraping data, you may not even need to interact with the scroll, or even the DOM at all.